# What is a dist build target folder in Yeoman / Grunt / Angular?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

In configuration readmes for generators such as [these](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/blob/master/docs/usage.md) I frequently see options such as `--dist-path='dist' customize build target folder, relative to cwd, default is dist`

Also, in my own grunt folder I see:

```
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: '../server/dist'
  };
```

What is that? It looks like it defaulted to my server directory but I have no idea what it is for. Can someone please explain the purpose of `dist` to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *dist* folder contains the minified/uglified/concatenated/etc version of your code. Yeoman generators usually run grunt/gulp tasks to prepare your application for production use by running several tasks and outputting the results in the for *dist* folder.

Dist stands for **dist**ribution.

More info [here](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/node-js/javascript-concatenation-and-minification-with-the-grunt-js-task-runer/).